# Перевод строки из массива в целое число

Tags: c

```
char stop_symbol[30]; // тут хранятся адреса запятых
char speed[3]; // тут сохраняется скорость
     /*тут есть код, но думаю, что он ненужен. Данные берутся с файла.*/
     /*Скорость*/
    for(int x = stop_symbol[7] + 1, y = 0; x < stop_symbol[8]; x++, y++)
    {
        speed[y] = String[x];
    }
    speed[-1] = '\0';
```

У меня вопрос, как данные из чаравского массива **speed** превратить в одно целое число.

Comment: `speed[-1] = '\0';`??? Что это и с какой целью сделано?

Comment: Как я понял, это нужно при выводе в файл. Что-бы выводился весь массив вплоть до '\n'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для перевода из си-строки в число используется функция `atoi()`

```
int number = atoi(speed);
```